# Inserting new ips into a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking

I have this program that list ip addresses on my network and if they are online or offline along with the mac address. i want the offline ips to be in a list so that i can check if that ip is not in the list it will it will display NEW.

idk what to do

```
import os

from getmac import get_mac_address

class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'

minr = int(input("Starting Ip: "))
maxr = int(input("Ending Ip: "))

ofip = ["192.168.2.0"]

while True:

    for num in range(minr, maxr + 1): #plus one is to include the last digit entered
        ip = "192.168.2." + str(num)

        from getmac import getmac

        exit_code = os.system("ping -n 1 -w 1 " + ip + " > nul") # Windows

        getmac.PORT = 44444  # Default: 55555

        if exit_code == 0:
            print(ip, bcolors.OKGREEN + "ONLINE " + bcolors.ENDC + bcolors.OKBLUE + get_mac_address(ip=ip, network_request=True) + bcolors.ENDC)

        elif exit_code != 0:
            print(ip, bcolors.FAIL + "OFFLINE" + bcolors.ENDC)
            ip = ofip

        elif exit_code != 0 and ip != ofip:
            print(ip, bcolors.OKGREEN + "NEW " + bcolors.ENDC + bcolors.OKBLUE + get_mac_address(ip=ip, network_request=True) + bcolors.ENDC)

        else:
            print(ip, bcolors.FAIL + "OFFLINE" + bcolors.ENDC)
```

i should see offline ip address that goes online print new

Comment: just use `ofip.append(ip)` in place of `ip=ofip`. This will add the IP to the list after `["192.168.2.0"]`. The next line of code `elif exit_code != 0 and ip != ofip:` will also be needed to changed to `elif exit_code != 0 and ip not in ofip:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MY problem has been solved and here is the code:

```
import os

from getmac import get_mac_address

class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    YELLOW = "\033[29m"
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'

minr = int(input("Starting Ip: "))
maxr = int(input("Ending Ip: "))

ofip = []

while True:

    for num in range(minr, maxr + 1): #plus one is to include the last digit entered
        ip = "192.168.2." + str(num)

        from getmac import getmac

        exit_code = os.system("ping -n 1 -w 1 " + ip + " > nul") # Windows

        getmac.PORT = 44444  # Default: 55555

        if exit_code == 0:
            if ip in ofip:
                print(ip, bcolors.HEADER + "NEW " + bcolors.ENDC + bcolors.OKBLUE + get_mac_address(ip=ip, network_request=True) + bcolors.ENDC)
                ofip.remove(ip)
            print(ip, bcolors.OKGREEN + "ONLINE " + bcolors.ENDC + bcolors.OKBLUE + get_mac_address(ip=ip, network_request=True) + bcolors.ENDC)

        elif exit_code != 0:
            print(ip, bcolors.FAIL + "OFFLINE" + bcolors.ENDC)
            ofip.append(ip)
```

Answer (score 0):

This line will not do what you are intending. You need to make a few changes.

`elif exit_code != 0 and ip != ofip:`

`ofip` is a list (at least it is at first) and `ip` is a string, `!=` will not work here. You should be using the `in` operator.

`elif exit_code != 0 and ip not in ofip:`

Second issue is addressing that `ip` is a string and `ofip` is a list (when you first assign it, later you set it to a string).

Instead of doing,

`ip = ofip`

try appending to the list

`ofip.append(ip)`

Last thing is that is that because of how your if/elif statements flow, the second elif will never run.
If the exit code is not 0 then it will always hit the first elif and will never hit the second one. Switch these. Put your more specific conditionals before your less specific ones.

Tip: you can use a set instead of a list for faster lookups.

```
import os

from getmac import get_mac_address

class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'

minr = int(input("Starting Ip: "))
maxr = int(input("Ending Ip: "))

ofip = ["192.168.2.0"]

while True:

    for num in range(minr, maxr + 1): #plus one is to include the last digit entered
        ip = "192.168.2." + str(num)

        from getmac import getmac

        exit_code = os.system("ping -n 1 -w 1 " + ip + " > nul") # Windows

        getmac.PORT = 44444  # Default: 55555

        if exit_code == 0:
            print(ip, bcolors.OKGREEN + "ONLINE " + bcolors.ENDC + bcolors.OKBLUE + get_mac_address(ip=ip, network_request=True) + bcolors.ENDC)

        elif exit_code != 0:
            if ip not in ofip:
                ofip.append(ip)
                print(ip, bcolors.OKGREEN + "NEW " + bcolors.ENDC + bcolors.OKBLUE + get_mac_address(ip=ip, network_request=True) + bcolors.ENDC)
            else:
                print(ip, bcolors.FAIL + "OFFLINE" + bcolors.ENDC)
```

Comment: could you please show what the code would look like because it is not working still

Comment: @parvbanks could you show what the code would look like its not working for me

Comment: Perhaps you could be more specific than "not working"? I added some code.

Comment: this is what i get with both our codes `$ python test.py
Starting Ip: 25
Ending Ip: 28
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 37, in <module>
    print(ip, bcolors.OKGREEN + "NEW " + bcolors.ENDC + bcolors.OKBLUE + get_mac_address(ip=ip, network_request=True) + bcolors.ENDC)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str`
 `

Comment: That is because `get_mac_address(ip=ip, network_request=True)` is returning `None`. That should be a an obvious fix for you. It wasn't my plan to write your code for you.